# Wondering where DTO classes belong in multimodule Maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, dto

I have Maven Spring Boot application with following modules:

- root (root pom)

  - backend (Spring backend, has many REST endpoints)
  - gateway (common configuration for api clients)

    - xxx-api (connects to xxx service, generates Java from openapi)
    - yyy-api (connects to yyy service, generates Java from openapi)

The xxx and yyy service have their own transport models that I need to convert (mostly simplify). I'm using mapstruct for this.

I'm wondering where should I put my mapstruct **@Mapper**s and **DTO** classes (they need to go together in same module). One side of me is telling me that **xxx-api** and **yyy-api** modules are ok for this (the closest to the source of data), the other says that **DTO**s (and in consequence **@Mapper**s) should be defined in the **backend** module (after all they are returned by the Spring controllers).

What's your take on this? I feel like I'm overcomplicating but I'm not sure if **DTO** classes can (by the design) **not** be placed in the **backend** module.

Comment: I feel like this question is opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not a question related to spring alone. It could be asked in any producer-consumer situation. The question can be restatet like "who describes the data".

The DTOs are the data model. So probably they need to be known by both sides. It would be a good guess to locate them in a shared module. This can be owned by the backend.

The probability is that the backend produes the answers, and the queries are more simple, so the the queries will often be arguments to functions, and the answers will often be a series of data rows. Thats what is done often. So the backend can own the types, but must export them to the con sumer.

Maybe it helps to think of modules that need not be written in the same language. If XML or JSON is used to transfer the data, the question is the same: who owns the regiment of describing the data. And that is probably safer to put into the producer.